# How to share wireless internet from laptop to desktop which doesn't have wifi adapter?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet

I have laptop which is connected to internet using WIFI. I need to connect desktop to internet. Desktop doesn't have wifi card. Can I set up my laptop to act like a switch/router and connect notebook's LAN port to PC LAN port? How to make PC to connect to internet?

---

**UPDATE**
There is no way to connect to wifi router directly (using cable). Only wifi access is available.

Comment: What OS? Windows? Windows 7 use Internet Connection Sharing: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/using-internet-connection-sharing#1TC=windows-7 - You _may_ need a crossover Ethernet cable if your network adapters don't automatically notice a normal patch cable has been used.

Comment: Both have Windows 7

Comment: You can do it with the tools provided by MS. Nonetheless I'd buy an inexpensive router and use it as wireless bridge instead.

Comment: Another idea: There are USB Wi-Fi adapters for ~$10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copied from [Sharing Laptop's Internet to Desktop through Ethernet cord?](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1742228/sharing-laptop-internet-desktop-ethernet-cord.html#r11213737):

> If your laptop has Internet access from wireless, you can use Internet
>   Connection Sharing on the laptop network adapter to share with the
>   desktop.
>
> - open the network control panel
> - change adapter settings
> - right click on the network adapter
> - select properties
> - the Sharing tab
> - and then check the box to allow sharing
>
> You can also bridge the two adapters on the laptop to share, although
>   to do that ICS must not be checked.
>
> This also assumes that at least one of the Ethernet adapters is
>   gigabit capable, and thus has auto-MDIX, so you don't need a crossover
>   cable.

Answer (score 1):

Goto adapter settings in windows,  select both the lan adapter and the wifi adapter > right-click > bridge connections

Answer (score 0):

Omar, you're a legend! I tried using the sharing option first, but it need constant maintenance. Your method works flawlessly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1144599)